# How to compare 2 files in bash then delete the ones in the first file that do not match with the second file

Tags: linux, bash, compare

So before i kind of crappily explained it but this is a challenge by my bos to create this code using only basic bash commmands to basically do this:

> while read line for file1.txt do;
>   search file2.txt for the matching line
>   if the matching line is found print to file3.txt; else go to next line in file1.txt and repeat in a loop until completion of file1.txt read.

I have no idea how to do this but i hope this makes it easier. I can not use diff comm or anything else because he said that would be to easy.

Comment: Are you intend to compare and replace 1.txt with 2.txt? Then why do you need to compare? go ahead and replace 1.txt with 2.txt

Comment: Please show an example of `1.txt`, `2.txt` and expected output. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I just updated it with the 2 files and a better explanation of the end goal at the bottom for why just replacing doesn't work

Comment: Next time post like 4 lines of each file with one differing line and the expected output.

Comment: I've never once had a boss who was willing to let me do no work, but instead gave me "challenges" to do.

Comment: I'm an intern ...

Answer (score 0):

```
# show the diff
diff 2.txt 1.txt

# update 1.txt to match
cp 2.txt 1.txt
```

Comment: it has to be completely in bash with no tools to assist

Comment: @mikedavidson Why?

Comment: my boss is a stickler

Comment: and read above because the end goal is to do a comparison between a whole system and a pol file then edit the pol file to match the system

Comment: Nope I actually have a boss read the lines above I am just trying to teach myself this because im eventually going to have to do this with a system and policy file